# Product alternatives query performance slow - Many to many tables and ROW_NUM(OVER PARTITION...) optimisation needed?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-8.0

When the user selects a product in my web app, I run a query to search for related alternatives based on product categories linked to the product via a many to many relationship with a category reference table.

With only 6000 products, the alternatives query takes more than 500ms and I expect the product count to x10 over the short term. Is there a better way to construct my query?

[image: Basic table entities]

The relationship is pretty simple: I have a reference table of categories (e.g. Shorts, pants, shirts, S, M, L, XL, cotton, etc.) and each product will have one or more categories linked to it. Appropriate FK indexes are in place.

My "alternatives" query tries to maximise the number of matching categories - The more matching categories that a product has, the higher its matching score. It also excludes the selected product and conflates product variants which are stored as separate products records ( ROW_NUM() OVER(PARTITION... ). The conflation avoids suggesting very similar products as alternatives (e.g. same product in different color)

To further rank products with the same category match score, a text relevance score is calculated (MATCH AGAINST fulltext) and the results are ordered by category match count and text relevance. The fulltext matching has very little effect on query performance, but the variant conflation takes about 200ms.

At this point, I cannot change the application/data model to normalise product variants.

This is the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT P.*, 
    (SUM(CASE WHEN C.category_id = 3 OR C.category_id = 11 OR C.category_id = 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS cat_score,
    MATCH(P.name, P.description) AGAINST('blue short sleeve shirt' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS rel_score,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY variant_group ORDER BY price ASC) variantIndex 
    FROM RPDB.Product P 
    JOIN Product_has_Category PC ON PC.product_id = P.product_id 
    JOIN Category C ON C.category_id = PC.category_id 
    WHERE P.product_id <> 123 AND variant_group <> 65
    GROUP BY P.product_id
) result
WHERE variantIndex = 1
ORDER BY cat_score DESC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Explain output (note that I simplified some field names in the above SQL):

[image: Explain output]

I don't care where the performance improvement comes from, so any aspect of the query that could be improved would be very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought through the problem again, starting from the Product_has_Category, to give me the set of relevant products (one or more categories) and joined that to the Products table before conflating variants and ordering for score.

This executes in ~150ms rather than 500ms.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        MATCH(P.name, P.desc_short, P.desc_long) AGAINST('blue short sleeve shirt' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS rel_score,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Organization_idOrganization, variant_group ORDER BY price ASC) variantIndex
    FROM Product P 
        JOIN (
            SELECT Product_idProduct, COUNT(Product_idProduct) AS cat_score
            FROM Product_has_Category PC 
            JOIN Category C ON PC.Category_idCategory = C.idCategory
            WHERE PC.Category_idCategory IN (3, 11, 18)
            GROUP BY Product_idProduct
            ) AS R 
            ON P.idProduct = R.Product_idProduct
    WHERE idProduct <> 123 AND variant_group <> 65 AND (P.price BETWEEN 0.0 AND 999999.0)
) AS PR
WHERE variantIndex = 1
ORDER BY cat_score DESC, rel_score DESC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite common to have the inadequate indexing for many-to-many tables.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table for the two indexes it *should* have and the indexes it should *not* have.